# Count number of elements greater than 1 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I hope you could help me with this.
I have a dataframe `df_test`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan,2,3,"male"],
                             [4,5,6,"female"],
                             [1,2,np.nan,"female"]],
                       columns=['a','b','c','sex'])


df_test 
         a  b  c       sex
    0  NaN  2  3.0     male
    1  4.0  5  6.0     female
    2  1.0  2  NaN     female
```

and for each category in the sex column I would like to count the number of values greater than 1 in each column of the dataframe `(a,b,c)`.

```
df_results 
         a_count  b_count  c_count       sex
    0    NaN      1        1             male
    1    2        2        1             female
```

Comment: please share the methods you've tried

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and aggregate to count the values :

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.nan,2,3,"male"],
                             [4,5,6,"female"],
                             [1,2,np.nan,"female"]],
                       columns=['a','b','c','sex'])

df_test.groupby('sex', sort=False).agg(lambda x : len(x.dropna()>1))
```

This gives us expected output :

```
        a  b  c
sex            
male    0  1  1
female  2  2  1
```

If at all you want those values the values to be Nan, then you can do

```
df_test.groupby('sex', sort=False).agg(lambda x : np.nan if len(x.dropna()) == 0 else len(x.dropna()))

          a  b  c
sex              
male    NaN  1  1
female  2.0  2  1
```

Since the column contains NaN values, pandas does some internal optimization to convert `int` to `float` internally. So you may have to explicitly convert the column to int.

Answer (score 0):

please correct

```
columns=[['a','b','c','sex']]
```

and replace with

```
columns=['a','b','c','sex']
```

then

```
pd.concat([df_test.sex, df_test.drop(columns=["sex"]) >= 1], axis=1).groupby("sex").sum().replace(0, np.nan).rename(columns=lambda x: x + "_count").reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code (I have assumed all values will be greater than or equal to 1 or nan based upon the example data)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df_test.values == 1, np.nan, df_test.values), columns = df_test.columns).groupby(“sex”).count().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let ust try:

```
(df_test.drop('sex', axis=1).ge(1)           # compare the data with `1`
   .groupby(df_test['sex'],sort=False).sum() # count the number of `True` with sum
   .add_suffix('_count')                     # add the suffix
   .reset_index()                            # make `sex` a column
)
```

Output:

```
      sex  a_count  b_count  c_count
0    male        0        1        1
1  female        2        2        1
```